# How to return List as a Iterable in Java

Tags: java, list, collections, return, iterable

I have searched both on Google and StackOverflow, but I cannot find an answer that satisfies me. That's why I'm here.

I'm currently trying to implement a generic tree from scratch. So, I have

```
public interface IPosition<E> {
    E getElement();
}
```

And I have

```
public class LinkedTree<E> extends ATree<E> {

    protected static class Node<E> implements IPosition<E> {
        private E element;
        private Node<E> parent;
        private List<Node<E>> children;

        public Node(E element, Node<E> parent, List<Node<E>> children) {
            this.element = element;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.children = children;
        }

        public E getElement() {
            return element;
        }
        public Node<E> getParent() {
            return parent;
        }
        public List<Node<E>> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }
    }

    protected Node<E> root = null;
    private int size = 0;

    public Node<E> createNode(E element, Node<E> parent, List<Node<E>> children) {
        return new Node<E>(element, parent, children);
    }

    protected Node<E> verify(IPosition<E> position) {
        Node<E> node = null;
        try {
            node = (Node<E>) position;
            if(node == node.getParent()) {
                throw new Exception("This position is no longer in the tree.");
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            System.out.println("Not a valid position type.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return node;
    }

    public Iterable<IPosition<E>> children(IPosition<E> parent) {
        return verify(parent).getChildren();        
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is I cannot do the

```
public Iterable<IPosition<E>> children(IPosition<E> parent) {
    return verify(parent).getChildren();        
}
```

because when I return with `verify(parent).getChildren()`, it says

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<LinkedTree.Node<E>> to Iterable<IPosition<E>>   LinkedTree.java
```

I also tried `return verify(parent).getChildren().iterator();`, I says

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator<LinkedTree.Node<E>> to Iterable<IPosition<E>>   LinkedTree.java
```

as well. So, I have read that we can use a loop to handle this, but I think there might be an easier/better way to do this, is there?

By the way, the reason why I **cannot** change `public Iterable<IPosition<E>> children(IPosition<E> parent)` to `public List<Node<E>> children(IPosition<E> parent)` because the given interface forces me to use `public Iterable<IPosition<E>> children(IPosition<E> parent)` and I cannot use Guava as well. That's why I'm struggling.

Would you please help me with this?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of wildcards?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I don't really know about that. ;w;

Comment: @RealSkeptic I read about it and I just realised that I have been using it for quite a while. But I don't know how to use it with this.

Comment: The issue isn't with `List` to `Iterable`, but in changing the element type.  You'll need to do something like `Iterable<? extends IPosition<E>>`.